SECURITY_SCAN artifacts fail to get uploaded to gitlab
Newbeee to CICD
I am running a CICD pipeline to scan my code. After the scanning the test task fails with the error
gl-sast-report.json: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... POST http://172.25.64.1:8000/api/v4/jobs/142/artifacts: 500 Internal Server Error  id=142 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=glcbt-64
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... POST http://172.25.64.1:8000/api/v4/jobs/142/artifacts: 500 Internal Server Error  id=142 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=glcbt-64
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... POST http://172.25.64.1:8000/api/v4/jobs/142/artifacts: 500 Internal Server Error  id=142 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=glcbt-64
FATAL: invalid argument      

The above error appears in the pipeline job
When I check the gitlab server logs I see No such file or directory exists error. Not sure if both the errors are related. Below is the error for gitlab
server logs ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/exceptions_json.log <==
gitlab-server  | {"severity":"ERROR","time":"2024-12-20T21:54:08.859Z","correlation_id":"01JFK10KG85R40P9DGAY4WMP2M","meta.caller_id":"POST /api/:version/jobs/:id/artifacts","meta.remote_ip":"172.18.0.1","meta.feature_category":"job_artifacts","meta.project":"customers-dev/clientapp12","meta.root_namespace":"customers-dev","meta.client_id":"user/1","meta.pipeline_id":40,"meta.job_id":141,"exception.class":"Errno::ENOENT","exception.message":"No such file or directory @ apply2files - /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/tmp/work/1734731648-816-0002-3020/gl-sast-report.json","exception.backtrace":["carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:319:in `chmod'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:319:in `chmod!'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:187:in `move_to'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:132:in `cache!'","app/uploaders/object_storage.rb:446:in `cache!'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:44:in `block in cache'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:42:in `map'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:42:in `cache'","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:146:in `file='","carrierwave (1.3.4) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:70:in `file='","activemodel (7.0.8.6) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:49:in `public_send'","activemodel (7.0.8.6) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:49:in `_assign_attribute'","activerecord (7.0.8.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:2

Below is my set up

Gitlab running locally
Gitlab runner in kubernetes cluster

Please let me know if you need any config files, I can provide. Dont want o bombard this place with a lot of words

Instead of using bind-mounts for the data/config/log volumes in the gitlab container, which apparently caused the problem, I switched to docker volumes.
Did not work
volumes:

./gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab’
./gitlab/data:/var/log/gitlab’

Worked
volumes:
- gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab
- gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab
volumes:
gitlab-runner:
driver: local
gitlab-config:
driver: local
gitlab-logs:
driver: local
gitlab-data:
driver: local
